# how to count files after submit in dropzone.js using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone.js to upload files and then count the files after submit using php, but why the result is 1 ??

My dropzone js:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#drop", {
 url: 'test.php',

 previewsContainer: "#previews",
 clickable: "#clickable",
 autoQueue: false,
 addRemoveLinks: true
});

document.querySelector("#butt").onclick = function() {
  myDropzone.enqueueFiles(myDropzone.getFilesWithStatus(Dropzone.ADDED));
};

myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
  myDropzone.removeFile(file);
});
myDropzone.on('sending', function (file, xhr, formData) {
 formData.append("Username", document.getElementById("Username").value);
 formData.append("token", document.getElementById("token").value);
});
```

My test.php :

```
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 

$storeFolder = 'uploads'; 
if(!empty($_FILES)) {
  $count = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
  $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];        
  $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds; 

  $targetFile =  $targetPath. $count."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];

  move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}else{
  return "fail";
}
```

Or maybe there is another method to count the files ?

Comment: do the files get uploaded?

Comment: have you tried with the option `uploadMultiple: true` ?

Comment: @RamRaider Yes, the files get uploaded ..

Comment: @Yoplaboom just tried it, but the files doesn't uploaded ..

Comment: @Yoplaboom after reading the docs, I think added 'uploadMultiple: true' is the right way, but the files doesn't uploaded ..

Comment: `test.php` will receive the files sequentially with a new request each time will it not - so on each request there is only 1 file. You could use a session variable as a counter perhaps and increment on each upload. ( never used Dropzone so this is guesswork )

Comment: Thanks guys, it resolved ..